# post array of arrays to webmethod using jQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, vb.net

jQuery Code to build array from gridvew rows:

```
var a = 0;
$('[id*=GridView_PaymentSchedule]').find('tr:has(td)').each(function () {
    payments[a] = []
    payments[a] = [$(this).find('td').eq(0)[0].innerHTML, $(this).find('td').eq(1)[0].innerHTML, $(this).find('td').eq(2)[0].innerHTML, $(this).find('td').eq(3)[0].innerHTML];
    a += 1;
});
```

My ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "PaymentPlan.aspx/SaveGridViewData",
    data: '{pPayments: ' + JSON.stringify({ payments: payments }) + '}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    traditional: true,
    success: function (response) {
    alert("Data sucessfully transmited.");
        window.location.reload();
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert("Data not transmited: error = " + response.responseText);
    }  
});
```

The webmethod is executed successfully, but all I get is an empty list of string, webmethod code is:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Sub SaveGridViewData(ByVal pPayments As List(Of string))
    Dim x As Integer
    x += 1
End Sub
```

I kept it simple, I have a breakpoint at `x += 1` so I can examine the `pPayments` parameter.

So what am I missing?

Comment: `data` should be an object, not a string, so just do `data: {pPayments: payments}`

Comment: Intelesense says `expected '}' at the } and then at the comma `syntax error` ....

Comment: Scratch that, had a wayward character in there.  I made that change and get the error, `Invalid JSON Primitive: payments` ....

Comment: That doesn't seem right. Most likely there's something else going wrong. Before your ajax call, do `var d = {pPayments: payments}; console.log(JSON.stringify(d));` and see what gets logged.

Comment: This is a web application I get console.log is undefined.  So I added an alert, shows `d` as `{"pPayments:":[["03/23/2018,"8.89:,"0.54","9.43"],["03/26/2018",8.89","0.54","9.43"]]}`.  There are two more elements, but I figured this was enough.

Comment: A browser should have `console` defined... Anyway, that's an array of arrays, not an array of strings, that's why it's not working. You need a list of a list of strings in your .NET code. I haven't written VB in years (pre-generics era) so I can't help you with that :).

Comment: Yes, it's an array of arrays, hence the title of the question.  I'm unable to find any example, either VB or C#, so if you have a C# example, please post it and I'll make the necessary adjustments.

Comment: Sorry, had some paying work that needed my attention. In C# I would just change the argument to `List<List<string>>`. But your solution makes more sense from a maintainability point of view. Happy coding.

Comment: I had tried `List<List<string>> with the same result.  In any event I got what I needed.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.  Turned out to be one line of additional code on the client side.  I changed how I constructed the JSON object, instead of a array of arrays I construct an array of objects:

**jQuery (ajax) Code:**

```
var thepayment = new Array();

$('[id*=GridView_PaymentSchedule]').find('tr:has(td)').each(function () {
    var obj = new Object;
    obj.paymentdate = $(this).find('td').eq(0)[0].innerHTML;
    obj.amount = $(this).find('td').eq(1)[0].innerHTML;
    obj.processingfee = $(this).find('td').eq(2)[0].innerHTML;
    obj.totalamount = $(this).find('td').eq(3)[0].innerHTML;

    thepayment.push(obj);
});
// This is the line of code that made the difference
// DTO stands for Data Transfer Object
// Then you JSON stringify it, not all at once.

// This DOES NOT work:
// '{pPayments: ' + JSON.stringify({ payments: thepayment }) + '}'

// This does:
var DTO = { 'pPayments': thepayment };

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "PaymentPlan.aspx/SaveGridViewData",
    data: JSON.stringify(DTO), // '{pPayments: ' + JSON.stringify({ payments: thepayment }) + '}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    traditional: true,
    success: function (response) {
        alert("Data sucessfully transmited.");
        window.location.reload();
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert("Data not transmited: error = " + response.responseText);
    }
```

});

**payments class:**

```
Public Class payments
    Public Sub New()
        MyClass.New("", "", "", "")
    End Sub
    Public Sub New(ByVal pPaymentdate As String, ByVal pAmount As String, ByVal pProcessingfee As String, ByVal pTotalamount As String)
        paymendate = pPaymentdate
        amount = pAmount
        processingfee = pProcessingfee
        totalamount = pTotalamount
    End Sub

    Public Property paymendate As String

    Public Property amount As String

    Public Property processingfee As String

    Public Property totalamount As String

End Class
```

**Web method:**

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Sub SaveGridViewData(ByVal pPayments As List(Of payments))
    ' Do Stuff
End Sub
```